# bash value comparison and get uniq results

Tags: bash, comparison

I have following situation

```
$ cat a.txt
AAAA-A000 rootvg
AAAA-B001 rootvg
AAAA-B002 rootvg
AAAA-A002 appvg
AAAA-A003 appvg
$ cat b.txt
AAAA-B003 rootvg
AAAA-B004 appvg
```

I want to know if the uniq value in the last column for example rootvg contains different values in the first column. The difference is defined as AAAA-A... and AAAA-B... and could be n-occurrence.

The result should look like this for a.tx

```
    rootvg ok # because in the first column are values with AAAA-A... AND AAAA-B...
    appvg notok # because in the first column are only values with AAAA-A...
for b.txt
     rootvg notok # because in the first column are only values with AAAA-B...
     appvg notok # because in the first column are only values with AAAA-B...
```

Any Idea, how to realize this in bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk you can make associative array in associative array:

```
[
  appvg: ["AAAA-A": 1],
  rootvg: ["AAAA-A": 1, "AAAA-B": 1],
]
```

And then count the length of the inner array (`["AAAA-A": 1]`):

```
% awk '{
  a[$2][substr($1, 1, 6)] = 1
}
END{
  for(key in a) {
    print key, (length(a[key]) > 1 ? "ok" : "notok")
  }
}' <<< "AAAA-A000 rootvg
AAAA-B001 rootvg
AAAA-B002 rootvg
AAAA-A002 appvg
AAAA-A003 appvg"
appvg notok
rootvg ok
```